# Having Problems With UISearchBar in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a UISearchBar to my UITableView.

This is the method they use to search:

```
- (void) searchTableView {

NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in listOfItems)
{
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
[searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
}

for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (titleResultsRange.length &gt; 0)
[copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}

[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil;
}
```

But I don't have a dictionary, I just want to search in my array 'exerciseArray' which is init like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.exerciseArray = rootLevel;
[rootLevel release];
```

When I NSLog it, I get:

```
exerciseArray: (
        {
        exerciseName = "Balance Board";
    },
        {
        exerciseName = "Barbell Seated Calf Raise";
    },
        {
        exerciseName = "Calf Press On The Leg Press Machine";
    },
        {
        exerciseName = "Calf Raises- With Bands";
    },
```

So can anyone help me modify the search method to fit the array I have? It seems to have a key in it.

I tried this but it did not work and crashed at line `NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

with error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2d6450`

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSLog(@"exerciseArray: %@", exerciseArray);
    for (NSString *sTemp in listOfItems)
    {
        if (sTemp) {
            NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
                [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NSDates are *already* in UTC (a.k.a. "GMT").

Comment: could you post the interface of your `UIViewController` derived class?

Comment: Please don't edit your questions so heavily that they no longer resemble the original contents. Search engines have already picked up your original content, here: http://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Problem+With+NSDate+Formatter - and now the links go to a different question. Don't do this. Post new questions instead!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an array of dictionaries with one key/value pair in each dictionary (exerciseName).  so for your dataset, it should be this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in exerciseArray)
{
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
}
...
```

If you post your VC code related to the array and also your tableview datasource methods, I have can modify it and show you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

For searching from table view i have tried this and i got success hope it will help you......

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    self.searching=NO;
    NSString *originalString;
    [self.filteredProductArray removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<self.exerciseArray.count; i++)
    {
        originalString=[[[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"exerciseName"] lowercaseString];
        if (!([originalString rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]].location==NSNotFound))
        {
            [self.filteredProductArray addObject:[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    if ([searchText isEqual:@""])
    {
        self.searching=NO;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe NSPredicates are good way to search in arrays.. You can refer to this link.. [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys)