# How To Add UIButton Below UITableVIew?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

My VC is a subclass of `UITableViewController` and I'm trying to add a `UIButton` at the bottom of the screen.

I know how to do this when my VC is a `UIView` with a `UITableView` object in it, but how can I add this button when I'm subclassing `UITableView`?  I tried adding it in IB but it only lets me add it as the table's footer, which is only visible when the bottom of the table is scrolled to.  Any ideas?

And also, how can I add an image behind the table while keeping the cells white? It's easy when the class is `UIView`, but not sure in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestion1 : You could have create a separate view which contains your UIButton and place below of the UITableView.

Remark : This is useful because when you scroll the tableView the default footer will be stick to bottom.

```
// position(change according to your position) of the bottom view 
                                             //and set the size of the button

UIView* bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 460.0, 300.0, 80.0)];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

// position(change according to your position) of the button inside bottomView
                                             //and set the size of the button
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44);

[myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a view
[bottomView addSubview:myButton]; // add the button to bottom view
[self.view addSubView:bottomView]; //add bottom view main view
```

Suggestion2 : you can use viewForFooterInSection delegate method. where you can create a view and add the UILabel. viewForFooterInSection returns the UIView, which you can return your view which contains the UILabel

Remark : when you scroll the tableView the default footer will move along with your tableView

NOTE :

> If your view is the subclass of UITableViewController, okay then change it to UIViewController and in your nib file Create a view and drag your tableView under the view and change the reference class to your UIViewController. Now create an IBOutlet of UITableView* myTableView and connect it to you nib file. you just need to change in your VC file for example self to [self.myTableView reloadData];

Comment: Its actually a UIButton, not a UILabel. Would this still work with option 1 you gave?

Comment: Thanks, can you just add the code that lets me add the new uiview as a subivew and place it below the table that would go in viewdidload? Thanks.

Comment: I have enhanced my answer and have written the code there itself. :)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, that code makes the button scroll with the footer of the tableview

Comment: No. it would not, that is why we kept the tableView and button separately in the different section. you can scroll your tableView but your button(which is added to bottomView) will stick to bottom always.

Comment: I copied you code directly into my `viewDidLoad` and I can only see the button when I scroll all the way down to the bottom of my table.

Comment: How it can possible?, is your tableView overlap the bottom view(set the backgroundcolor of bottomView to some color and make sure tableView should not overlap the bottomView). the total height of UIView for iPhone is 480. then set the height for tableView 450 and for bottomView 30.  Just change the frame position of tableView and bottomView to make sure that both should not overlap..

Comment: OK, that may be the problem.  How can I change the heights for both my uiview and the bottom uiview so they fit? I will then accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: why you want to change the frame size of uiview? you just need to change the frame size of your tableView and bottom view. okay i got it your view is the subclass of UITableViewController, okay then change it to UIViewController and in your nib file Create a view and drag your tableView under the view and change the reference class to your UIViewController. Now create an IBOutlet of UITableView* myTableView and connect it to you nib file. you just need to change in your VC file for example self to [self.myTableView reloadData]; or else paste your code to pastebin.com

Comment: Control-V, I have to have it as  UITableView subclass not a UIView, because I couldn't get search working unless it as a talbe subclass.

Comment: Hahaha funny, who told you can not search working if you do not subclass to UITableViewController. Ohh you only asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501032/having-problems-with-uisearchbar-in-uitableviewcontroller. Read This( http://bit.ly/rujhui )

Comment: Ok thanks, i got search working when switching to Uiview i think. Thanks.

Comment: **Feel free to ask anytime..**

Answer (score 5):

good code for this

```
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)] autorelease];        
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 40); 
[btn setTitle:@"showProfile" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(your_function) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerView addSubview:btn];        
tbl.tableFooterView = headerView;
```

Comment: `tbl.tableFooterView = headerView;` assigning a header as a footer — funny.

Comment: @vikingosegundo good when you hold the phone in inverted portrait mode ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with these approaches is that the `UIButton` will not remain at the bottom of the screen for different device sizes since you're setting a fixed height for the footer and such footer is fixed to the table's bottom (which extends only to the last cell's bottom).

What I ended up doing was to get a handle of the main window's view and fix the button to the bottom of such.

I can provide code if someone would find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add `UIView` bellow in `tableView`. subview of view is button and direct create `IBAction` in your ViewController. i am using it

Answer (score 0):

To have a view above a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewController` fixed to bottom of the screen (with Auto-Layout):

**Swift 4**

```
// add inset to bottom of the table view, bottom = view height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)

// create the view
let myView = UIView()
myView.backgroundColor = .red
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(myView)

myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note that you have to insert this code in `viewDidAppear()` in order to prevent the table view to have a greater zIndex than `myView`.